# Extract maximum value from a dictionary with keys that begin with the same value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have dictionary like this:

```
Counter({'3:C': 22500, '4:G': 21096, '1:D': 20778, '0:F': 18400, '7:H': 10788, '8:E': 9160, '8:H': 8137, 
'7:E': 5259, '8:D': 4690, '1:E':4063, '6:A': 3592, '1:H': 2840, '10:G': 2689, '0:A': 2437, '6:F': 2436, 
'8:C': 2435, '4:B': 1643, '7:D': 1588, '7:I': 1508, '7:J': 1390, '
 3:A': 1314, '6:I': 1183, '8:J': 1177, '6:J': 948, '8:I': 750, '10:B':
 677, '2:I': 470, '1:A': 406, '1:J': 360, '6:H': 317, '6:E': 97})
```

I need to extract maximum for values which keys start with same number. For example if i have '3:C': 22500 and '3:A': 1314 i need to get '3:C' because that combination occur more times and in that way for all other values. How can i get that?
My expected output is:

```
0:F
1:D
2:I
3:C
4:G
6:A
8:E
7:H
10:B
```

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to do it?

Comment: I don't know how to find elements which keys start with same number and then get maximum for those values.

Comment: Did you try writing a `for` loop over all the items in the counter, and using the `startswith` method to check if a string starts with a given character or substring?

Comment: Yes, but I failed.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over the dictionary items and keep a separate dict for that holds the current max key/value tuple for that number. You get the number by splitting the key on `:`. Once you have the maxes, you can go through the maxes dict, pull out the keys (and sort if you want).

```
counts = Counter({'3:C': 22500, '4:G': 21096, '1:D': 20778, '0:F': 18400, '7:H': 10788, '8:E': 9160, '8:H': 8137, 
'7:E': 5259, '8:D': 4690, '1:E':4063, '6:A': 3592, '1:H': 2840, '10:G': 2689, '0:A': 2437, '6:F': 2436, 
'8:C': 2435, '4:B': 1643, '7:D': 1588, '7:I': 1508, '7:J': 1390, '3:A': 1314, '6:I': 1183, '8:J': 1177, '6:J': 948, '8:I': 750, '10:B':677, '2:I': 470, '1:A': 406, '1:J': 360, '6:H': 317, '6:E': 97})

maxes = dict()

for k, v in counts.items():
    n, l = k.split(":")
    if n not in maxes or v > maxes[n][1]:
        maxes[n] = (k, v)

# maxes is a dict like:
# {'3': ('3:C', 22500), '4': (...}

sorted((k for k, v in maxes.values()), key=lambda x: int(x.split(':')[0]))
# ['0:F', '1:D', '2:I', '3:C', '4:G', '6:A', '7:H', '8:E', '10:G']
```